# How to mark a product as fulfilled with new FulfillmentOrders API?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am developing a script to automatically change the status on a specific service in an order to be fulfilled on Shopify. However, with the new FulfillmentOrders API, in step 1 in the documentation here, https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/fulfillment/order-management-apps/manage-fulfillments#step-1-retrieve-an-order

I am retrieving an empty array for the order.
`{"fulfillment_orders":[]}`

This product is digital, and does not require shipping. I'm wondering if that could possibly be the issue for it not showing up in fulfillment_orders.

How can we mark this product as fulfilled by the new FulfillmentOrders API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be due to `read_merchant_managed_fulfillment_orders` or `write_merchant_managed_fulfillment_orders` access scopes not being requested.

Source; https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/fulfillment-orders-returns-empty-array-no-matter-the-order/m-p/1773228/highlight/true#M83981